# MYSQL DISTINCT and ORDER BY together

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following

```
item_id    position_number         position_date
   1             9              2013-06-29 15:12:58
   2             7              2013-07-25 15:12:58
  18             5              2013-07-08 12:07:00
  13             9              2013-07-08 12:07:00
```

I want to get the items group by position_number and order by position_date DESC, so the query will return the following:

```
item_id    position_number         position_date
  13             9              2013-07-08 12:07:00
   2             7              2013-07-25 15:12:58
  18             5              2013-07-08 12:07:00
```

I've been implementing some of the solutions that use DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but not get the desired result.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solved it?

Comment: View my edited answer and http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b39b7/4

Comment: you wished result are not ordered by position_date , but look now my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  position_number, MAX(position_date) position_date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY position_number
        ) b ON a.position_number = b.position_number AND
                a.position_date = b.position_date
ORDER   BY a.position_number DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b39b7/1)

Comment: +1. This returns the specified resultset. But we also notice that with other data, if the same "maximum" position_date for a particular position_number appears on more than one row, this will return multiple rows for that position_number. (The example data doesn't include this case, so it's not clear what the desired output looks like in that case.)

Answer (score 3):

Given your example data, this query will return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT t.item_id
     , t.position_number
     , t.position_date
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(n.item_id) AS max_item_id
           FROM mytable n
          GROUP BY position_number
       ) m
   JOIN mytable t
     ON t.item_id = m.max_item_id
  ORDER BY t.position_number DESC
```

**NOTE** This is choosing a single `item_id` for each position_number. This is assuming that a given item_id will appear only once, and have a single position_number. (If an item_id can be associated with multiple postion_number, the query can be tweaked. This is using the `MAX()` function to choose the `item_id` with the largest value. (The only example of a row being excluded is item_id=1.)

Answer (score 2):

try this

> <strike>select * from your_table  group by position_number order by position_date DESC</strike>

EDIT:

```
 SELECT `item_id`, max(`position_number`) position_number , max(`position_date`) position_date FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY POSITION_NUMBER 
ORDER BY POSITION_DATE DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b39b7/10)

Comment: I think, that wont work in MySQL. When you use grouping, information regarding other columns is lost and one of the columns for the data is "randomly" selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b39b7/4)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
    GROUP BY POSITION_NUMBER 
    ORDER BY POSITION_DATE DESC
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess the reason may be because your query doesn't return the expected result. Besides, this is non-standard SQL and some people may not like it to the point of downvoting too, even despite the fact that some SQL products support it. In fact, though, the reason would probably not be so much the non-standardness as that this kind of query doesn't guarantee the same results every time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY POSITION_NUMBER ORDER BY POSITION_DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_BY and either MIN or MAX to decide which date in the group you want to use for sorting.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY position_number ORDER BY MAX(position_date) DESC;
```